# Screen flickering in Ubuntu 22

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, display, flicker

[Flickeringscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0M2CF.jpg)

My laptop screen suddenly started flickering few days ago like shown in the above image. I got my laptop cleaned up and the flickering went away for a few days but started again now. It seems to flicker at boot up for a few minutes,  then doesn't flicker. But if I keep using the laptop for a few hours it starts flickering again

The laptop model is Asus-Tuf-f15.
It has 16gb ram, Intel i5 processor and a Nvidia Geforce RTX 3050 Ti graphic card
I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on it

The graphic card driver is nouveau and its i915 for the intel processor.

Kindly let me know if you need to know any more information to solve the issue.

Comment: Check for a loose connection.  Flickering after long periods is usually relate to loose cables or heat.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Will update you if it works out